# my ajax call is getting correct response but isn't doing anything

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm trying to make a like/dislike button in ajax. The ajax is sending my data to a separate file where it is saved in a database and that file sends back the successful response `{"status":"success","message":"Like has been saved.","data":{"like":"1"}}` that I got from the chrome network response window. However the code in `$ajax(...)`.done isn't working

I have console.logged and var.dumped every bit of code i possibly could. my data IS being sent to my database which should mean that the SQL and the like class is correct. I've also tried simply `console.log` 'ging the response "res" and putting the rest in comments, but that again gives me nothing

```
<div>
    <a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $post->id ?>" class="like">Like</a>  
    <a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $post->id ?>" class="dislike" style="display:none;">Dislike</a>
    <span class='likes' data-id="<?php echo $post->id ?>"><?php echo $post->getLikes(); ?></span> people like this
</div>
```

```
$("a.like, a.dislike").on("click",function(e){
      var postId = $(this).data("id");
      if($("a.like")){
        var type = 1;
      }else if($("a.dislike")){
        var type = 0;
      }
      var elLikes = $(this).siblings(".likes");
      var likes=elLikes.html();

      $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "ajax/postlike.php",
          data: {postId: postId, type:type},
          dataType: "json",
      })
      .done(function( res ) {
          console.log(res);
          if(res.status=="succes"){
              console.log(res);

              if(res.data.like=="1"){
                  likes++;
                  elLikes=html(likes);
                  $("a.like").css("display","none");
                  $("a.dislike").css("display","inline-block");

              } else if(res.data.like=="0"){
                  likes--;
                  elLikes=html(likes);
                  $("a.dislike").css("display","none");
                  $("a.like").css("display","inline-block");
              }
          }
      });
      e.preventDefault();

});
```

```php
if(!empty($_POST)){
        try {
            $postId=$_POST['postId'];
            $type=htmlspecialchars($_POST['type']);
            $userId=$_SESSION['user_id'];

            $l = new Like();
            $l->setPostId($postId);
            $l->setUserId($userId);
            $l->setType($type);
            $l->save();

            $res = [
                "status" => "success",
                "message" => "Like has been saved.",
                "data" =>[
                    "like" => $type
                ]
            ];

        }catch (trowable $t) {
            $res = [
                'status' => 'failed',
                'message' => $t->getMessage()
            ];
        }
        echo json_encode($res);
        var_dump($res);
    }
```

what I expected to happen was that Ajax sent the JSON data to the php code, that put it in a database, which works. Then gives a successful response to the Ajax, also works. The Ajax would then switch out the like/dislike buttons whilst adding or taking 1 like from the span "likes". It however does absolutely nothing

I'm almost 100% certain that the problem is something stupid that I'm overlooking, but i really can't find it.

Comment: can you add and var_dump or output at the beginning to Check this value received in php, and you it?? php is storing in your DB??

Comment: try removing `dataType: "json"`. Also add a `.fail` handler to your ajax request.  `.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
   console.log('failed')
});`

Comment: @walternuñez what parameter specifically are you talking about? i've pretty much tried them all and they all came back with the expected result

Comment: @bassxzero i did as you suggested. first getting rid of the dataType and i'm now getting console.log in my chrome console, i also tried the .fail parameter that you suggested separatly and then I got failed. thank you for replying btw

Comment: That `var_dump()` at the end of your PHP script may cause issues since it's an AJAX request and it'll likely throw an error for headers already being set.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a return data type for the ajax request to expect, and the actual returned value isn't what you specified, then your error/fail function will be triggered if you have one. This is because adding `dataType: "json"` causes you're ajax try and parse your return value as json and when it fails, it triggers your error handler. It's best to omit the dataTaype and then add a try catch with `JSON.parse` in your done function, to get around this.

E.G

```
.done(function (string_res) {
    console.log(string_res);
    try {
        var json_obj = JSON.parse(string_res);
        console.log(json_obj);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('failed to parse');
    }   
    // do work/operations with json_obj not string_res
})
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log('failed')
});
```

Comment: thank you! this is extremely helpfull! I'm not quite done yet, but i'm getting there and with post the results later.

Answer (score 0):

Typo in 'success' in on line: `if(res.status=="succes"){`

Comment: This doesn't explain why his `console.log(res);` doesn't get executed.

Comment: I didn't see the earlier `console.log()` before the conditional as it's there twice.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
    console.log(error)
},
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response)
}
```

in your Ajax function, to know what happen in the server side with the response.

Comment: This was a great answer. I don't understand who would mark it down.